# cloned prefab is automatically following my camera against my wishes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, clone

a prefab I instantiate (the boss of my game) is following my camera whenever this script is active, which is not what I'm telling it to do. Well, to be more accurate, when the camera goes to the right, the cloned prefab goes to the left, and vice versa. If I have the boss already in the scene and start the game, it does everything I tell it to, and doesn't follow the camera. The prefab only does half the things and yes, I did apply the changes to the prefab several times. I know it's not attaching itself to the camera automatically because I moved the camera in the scene view with this script off and it didn't follow my camera in-game.

The boss isn't even being referenced in this script. I am absolutely positive that the problem isn't even script wise. But it occurs when this script that has nothing to do with the boss is active. So my question is, can I tell the boss script in some way to blind itself to this script? Or better yet, is there something in Unity that can cause this, to which at that end I can fix? The only thing this script does is follow the player's characters based on whenever you switch between them. And the boss does follow the camera regardless of whatever character you have active at the time so it has nothing to do with that either. Lastly, the camera is not being referenced in the boss script at all, or in the script attached to another 2D trigger collider that instantiates the boss.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform player;
public Transform player2;
private bool idleFollow = true;
private bool mountFollow = false;
public theWatcher wMana;
public tulMove tulia;
private bool alphaGirl;
[HideInInspector]
public bool blinking = false;
[HideInInspector]
public bool vTul = true;

void Update ()
{
    CameraSwitching (); 
}

void CameraSwitching()
{

    if (!wMana.alphaGirl && !wMana.switched && vTul && wMana.cur_mana > 0f && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        vTul = false;
        return;
    }

    if (!vTul && wMana.cur_mana > 0f && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        vTul = true;
        return;
    }

    if (!vTul && wMana.cur_mana <= 0) {
        vTul = true;
    }

    if (vTul && wMana.cur_mana <= 0 && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        vTul = true;
    }

    if (!wMana.paused && vTul){
        transform.position = new Vector3 (player.position.x + .5f, player.position.y + .55f, -7.75f);
    }

    if (!wMana.paused && !vTul) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (player2.position.x + .5f, player2.position.y + .55f, -7.75f);
    }
    if (wMana.switched) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (player2.position.x + .5f, player2.position.y + .55f, -7.75f);
    }
    if (!wMana.switched) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (player.position.x + .5f, player.position.y + .55f, -7.75f);
    }
} 
}
```

this is the code to spawn my boss. I know it's not this because I used other prefabs besides my boss and those were working fine.

[image]

Comment: 1) presumably this is a script attached to the camera to make it follow the player. 2) presumably this script is *not* attached to the boss. 3) "Well, to be more accurate, when the camera goes to the right, the cloned prefab goes to the left, and vice versa" that sounds exactly like what would happen when things are working correctly. 4) show the inspector for the instantiated prefab that is misbehaving.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. But it isnt working correctly. The boss literally tranlastes left and right when the camera translates right or left. There are plenty of other objects in the scene that remain stationary or move independently regardless of what the camera is doing

Comment: Sounds like I need to see a short video of the problematic behavior.

Comment: can you show us the code in which you instantiate the boss

Comment: sure. i just put up a screenshot of it

Answer (score 0):

so, since there are no known solutions to a problem with a random, unrelated cause, I just decided to work around the issue. What I did was have the boss already placed in the scene and made a trigger collider activate the existing GameObject. If the player dies, I'll just move the boss back to his original position and deactivate him. It sucks I can't have a prefab of this character for whatever reason, but at least it's a character you only have to beat once anyway.